# Rewrite URL in urlManager Yii Framework

Tags: yii

In file config main.php:

```
'/my-acc/<slug:.*>' => 'user/profile/<slug>',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

But, when I create URL:

```
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('user/profile', array('slug'=>'acc1');
```

Returns the result `mydomain/user/profile?slug=acc1`, without `mydomain/my-acc/acc1`.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should works:

```
'my-acc/<slug>' => 'user/profile',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `urlManager rules`

```
 'my-acc/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+>' => 'user/profile',
```

Modify regular expression according to your need.

To allow only digits

```
 'my-acc/<slug:\d+>' => 'user/profile',
```

To allow string (without -,_)

```
 'my-acc/<slug:\w+>' => 'user/profile',
```

Answer (score 0):

if the above two answer works ,then ignore , other wise try this ,

have you added .htaccess file in this path ? , move the .htacess file where the root directory( .index.php file exist )

```
www

 - index.php
 - .htaccess
```

and in main.php file

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
     ...,        
),
```